# kotlin, emoji keyboard overlapping content

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext, emoji

image->
[first image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1V8j40dG2MJr8rPG9iKUXxJzL6xBEXmgQ/view?usp=sharing)

image->
[second](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iGXQe_Vs1wkYOhTvPwhJEJjw4Xjn4u0p/view?usp=sharing)

image->
[3](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1znBoD-cjFY6ISRUU-FnOZUCGvH-g2PqW/view?usp=sharing)

Hi all, ran into a problem with the keyboard overlapping content. I decided to add emoji keyboard in the application, for this I used this library:( https://github.com/vanniktech/Emoji/tree/master ),

here is how I implemented it in activity:

```
  val emojiPopup = EmojiPopup(
            rootView = binding.root,
            editText = binding.editTextChat,
            onEmojiBackspaceClickListener = { Log.d(TAG, "Clicked on Backspace") },
            onEmojiClickListener = { emoji -> Log.d(TAG, "Clicked on Emoji " + emoji.unicode) },
            onEmojiPopupShownListener = { binding.chooseEmodjiButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_keyboard) },
            onSoftKeyboardOpenListener = { px ->
                Log.d(
                    TAG,
                    "Opened soft keyboard with height $px"
                )
            },
            onEmojiPopupDismissListener = { binding.chooseEmodjiButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.baseline_insert_emoticon_24) },
            onSoftKeyboardCloseListener = { Log.d(TAG, "Closed soft keyboard") },
            pageTransformer = PageTransformer(),
            searchEmoji = NoSearchEmoji,
        )

       binding.chooseEmodjiButton.setOnClickListener {
            emojiPopup.toggle()
        }
```

. In the screenshots provided you can see the problem, I need help very much. I should clarify that there's no problem opening a regular keyboard. another problem (I'll point out in the same question, it's just related to this one) I circled the button in red on 1 of the screenshots (when you click on it, you can choose which keyboard to use, but when you open the keyboard with emoji, the screen just goes a little dark and as I realized the keyboard with emoji overlaps this content).

Comment: Not quite sure, as I haven't use it in a while, if this is what you need: https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/touch-and-input/keyboard-input/visibility#Respond. I think you need some sort of attribute to set so your UI would be above the keyboard

Comment: I decided to do it this way, but I do not like it, because on some devices the keyboard is displayed differently (there is no indentation at all), here is my solution:
    private fun adjustContentViewHeight(isEmojiPopupShown: Boolean) {
        val contentLayout = binding.constraintLayout11

        val layoutParams = contentLayout.layoutParams as ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams
        if (isEmojiPopupShown) {
            layoutParams.bottomMargin = 100
        } else {
            layoutParams.bottomMargin = 0
        }
        contentLayout.layoutParams = layoutParams
    }

Comment: Well, if that works for you, that's good. Please post that as an answer so it can help others in the future

Comment: my solution is bad, because I have set the indentation at the bottom 100, and this is suitable only for my phone, other phones need a different indentation. needs to improve my solution, then can post it as an answer.

Comment: You can post your current solution, then update it later if you found a better one